# NTH_VALUE MySQL. First value is null why?

Tags: mysql, window-functions

Why first value is null for nth value column??
Here's the query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, role_, dept, salary, NTH_VALUE(salary,2) OVER(ORDER BY salary ASC) FROM emp_table;
```

The result:

```
Jenifer Jhones  Junior Data Scientist   Retail  2800    null
Katrina Allen   Junior Data Scientist   Retail  3000    3000
David   Smith   Associate Data Scientist    Retail  4000    3000
Claire  Brennan Associate Data Scientist    Automative  4300    3000
Steve   Hoffman Associate Data Scientist    Finance 5000    3000
Chad    Wilson  Associate Data Scientist    Healthcare  5000    3000
Dianna  Wilson  Senior Data Scientist   Healthcare  5500    3000
Nian    Zhen    Senior Data Scientist   Retail  6500    3000
Roy Collins Senior Data Scientist   Retail  7000    3000
Karene  Nowak   Senior Data Scientist   Automative  7500    3000
Dorothy Wilson  Senior Data Scientist   Healthcare  7700    3000
Eric    Hoffman Lead Data Scientist Finance 8500    3000
Tracy   Norris  Manager Retail  8500    3000
```

Comment: Because the window includes only the 1st row.

Comment: Study the difference between frame definitions with and without ORDER BY.

Comment: @forpas I was hoping it would show 3000 because I'm finding the 2nd least salary in this database